# PHP function to find out the number of parameters passed into function?

Tags: php, function, arguments

Is there a PHP function to find the number of parameters to be received/passed to a particular function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

> Gets the number of arguments passed to the function.

Here is an example taken right from the link above,

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs\n";
}

foo(1, 2, 3);   
?>
```

Which outputs,

```
Number of arguments: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `func_num_args`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Answer (score 1):

[func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get the value of arguments

From the documentation :

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs\n";
}

foo(1, 2, 3);   
?>
```

The above example will output:

Number of arguments: 3

Answer (score 1):

func_number_args() is limited to only the function that is being called. You can't extract information about a function dynamically outside of the function at runtime.

If you're attempting to extract information about a function at runtime, I recommend the Reflection approach:

```
if(function_exists('foo'))
{
 $info = new ReflectionFunction('foo');
 $numberOfArgs = $info->getNumberOfParameters(); // this isn't required though
 $numberOfRequiredArgs = $info->getNumberOfRequiredParameters(); // required by the function

}
```